# Getting an invalid JWT token when I try to register a django user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

trying to figure out why I'm getting an invalid token error given my code below. I'm testing registration and authentication via my API.

I create a dummy account and then check my email for the verification link. Everything is working great until I click on the link in the email and receive a 400 bad request and due to my debugging the error is caused by an "Invalid Token".

Here is my code:

`views.py`

```
import jwt

from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.conf import settings

#from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from rest_framework import generics ,status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema
from drf_yasg import openapi

from .models import NewUser
from .serializers import RegisterSerializer, EmailVerificationSerializer, LoginSerializer
from .utils import ConfirmEmail


class CustomUserCreate(generics.GenericAPIView):

    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        user_data = serializer.data
        user = NewUser.objects.get(email=user_data['email'])
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user).access_token
        current_site = get_current_site(request).domain
        relativeLink = reverse('users:email-verify')
        absurl = 'http://'+current_site+relativeLink+"?token="+str(token)
        email_body = 'Hi '+user.username + \
            ' Use the link below to verify your email \n' + absurl
        data = {'email_body': email_body, 'to_email': user.email,
                'email_subject': 'Verify Your Email'}

        ConfirmEmail.send_email(data)
        return Response(user_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


class VerifyEmail(views.APIView):

    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = EmailVerificationSerializer
    token_param_config = openapi.Parameter(
        'token', in_=openapi.IN_QUERY, description='Description', type=openapi.TYPE_STRING)
 

    @swagger_auto_schema(manual_parameters=[token_param_config])
    def get(self, request):
        token = request.GET.get('token')
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY).decode("utf-8")
            user = NewUser.objects.get(id = payload['user_id'])
            if not user.is_verified:
                user.is_verified = True
                user.save()

            return Response({'email': 'Successfully Activated'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError as identifier:
            return Response({'error': 'Activation Expired'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except jwt.exceptions.DecodeError as identifier:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid token'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        


class LoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

`serializers`

```
from django.contrib import auth

from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed

from users.models import NewUser


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8, max_length=68, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password','first_name','last_name')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

class EmailVerificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=555)

    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = ['token']


class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255, min_length=3)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=68, min_length=6, write_only=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, min_length=3, read_only=True)
    
    tokens = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_tokens(self, obj):
        user = NewUser.objects.get(email=obj['email'])

        return {
            'refresh': user.tokens()['refresh'],
            'access': user.tokens()['access']
        }

    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = ['email', 'password', 'username', 'tokens']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email', '')
        password = attrs.get('password', '')
        filtered_user_by_email = NewUser.objects.filter(email=email)
        user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if not user:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Invalid credentials, try again')
        if not user.is_active:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Account disabled, contact admin')
        if not user.is_verified:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Email is not verified')

        return {
            'email': user.email,
            'username': user.username,
            'tokens': user.tokens()
        }

        return super().validate(attrs)
```

`models`

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager

from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken


class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, db_index=True, default=None)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    #newsletter = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


    def tokens(self):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token)
        }
```

Not sure what the problem is, I've tried de-bugging to my extent but now I've hit a wall. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: here is my settings file

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}


SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=10),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
}
```

project `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('api/token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('bucket_api.urls', namespace='bucket_api')),
    path('auth/', include('users.urls')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('', include('bucket.urls', namespace='bucket')),
    path('swagger/', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    path('redoc/', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),

]
```

app `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', CustomUserCreate.as_view(), name="register"),
    path('login/', LoginAPIView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path('email-verify/', VerifyEmail.as_view(), name="email-verify"),
    path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    #path('logout/blacklist/', BlacklistTokenUpdateView.as_view(), name='blacklist'),
]
```

according to jwt.io , my token should be valid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I finally managed to solve the error. First and foremost, when you are debugging, it will help commenting out `exceptions` to view the actual errors. I should of known this but I was stubborn in my methods...

Anyways, you have to state the type of algorithm the JWT was generated in when using `JWT.decode`. As you see, here is my new payload, with the added `HS256` algo.
`payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms='HS256')`

Hope this helps you in the future!

Answer (score 0):

you can using django rest framework JWT like this

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',

    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
    'JWT_GET_USER_SECRET_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PUBLIC_KEY': None,
    'JWT_PRIVATE_KEY': None,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_LEEWAY': 0,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=300),
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': None,
    'JWT_ISSUER': None,

    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': False,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),

    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,

}
```

urls.py

```
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token
from rest_framework_jwt.views import refresh_jwt_token
from rest_framework_jwt.views import verify_jwt_token
from django.urls import path
#...

urlpatterns = [
    '',
    # ...

    path('api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    path('api-token-refresh/', refresh_jwt_token),
    path('api-token-verify/', verify_jwt_token),
]
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the help, I'm actually using `rest_framework_simplejwt` , couldn't get your code to work. I also have configured my JWT settings in my code, please see the updated post for new info.